# Not able to deduce why NullPointerException occurs at one part of code and not in the other

Tags: android, android-listview, arraylist, nullpointerexception

In my application, I am passing an Arraylist from one activity to another. FlipCardActivity is the parent activity (Activity A) and RecipientsActivity is the child Activity (Activity B). I pass an empty RecipientArray (ArrayList) from A to B using putExtra. In activity B, I check whether ArrayList's size is zero and if it is zero, another activity (Activity C) is called which then adds items to the arraylist and returns it to Activity B. In B, I use ListView to show the items. I have a "Back" button in activity B which finishes B and restarts activity A. Again when I click on an EditText activity B is started. Now I still have items in the ArrayList but when I set the adapter to the ListView to show the items it gives a NullPointerException. I am not able to figure out why this error comes because I repeat the same piece of code in OnActivityResult and it doesn't give me any error.

Here is part of my code:

In Activity A:

```
btn_rec = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_rec);
    btn_rec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent rec_Intent = new Intent(FlipCardActivity.this,
                    RecipientsActivity.class);
            rec_Intent.putExtra("RecArray", RecipientArray);
            startActivityForResult(rec_Intent, NO_OF_RECIPIENTS);

        }
    });
```

here activity B is started when button btn_rec is clicked.

In Activity B:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RecipientArray = (ArrayList<Person>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(
            "RecArray");

    Log.e("Recipient Array", "size = " + RecipientArray.size());
    if (RecipientArray.size() == 0) {  //activity C is started here
        Intent rec_addr_Intent = new Intent(RecipientsActivity.this,
                RecipientAddressActivity.class);
        rec_addr_Intent.putExtra("RecArray", RecipientArray);
        startActivityForResult(rec_addr_Intent, REC_INFO);
    } else {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
        int size = prefs.getInt("size", 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            String json = prefs.getString("RecList_" + i, "");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Person p = gson.fromJson(json, Person.class);
            RecipientArray.add(p);
        }
        // Log.e("RecListActivity","Size of arraylist"+RecipientArray.size());

        this.m_adapter = new CustomListAdapter(RecipientsActivity.this,
                R.layout.recipients_list, RecipientArray);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rec_list);
        list.setAdapter(m_adapter);//I get NullPointer Exception here
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipients);
    addListenerForButtons();
}
```

...

```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REC_INFO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        RecipientArray = (ArrayList<Person>) data
                .getSerializableExtra("RecArray");
        Log.e("Before for", "size = " + RecipientArray.size());
        this.m_adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,
                R.layout.recipients_list, RecipientArray);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rec_list);
        list.setAdapter(m_adapter);
      }
```

Same piece of code related to ListView is here.

Kindly, please help me asap. Please let me know if I some more code or Logcat info is required.

Logcat File:

```
01-06 11:52:55.998: E/AddrAdctivity(1278): On Pause
01-06 11:52:56.018: E/Before for(1278): size = 1
01-06 11:52:59.251: E/In onpause(1278): Hola
01-06 11:52:59.351: E/FlipCardActivity(1278): This activity is restarted
01-06 11:52:59.351: E/FlipCardActivity(1278): Size of arraylist 1
01-06 11:53:04.907: E/In edt onclick(1278): Hello
01-06 11:53:04.967: E/FlipCardActivity(1278): This activity is paused
01-06 11:53:04.997: E/Recipient Array(1278): size = 1
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start      activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.postcare2/com.sample.postcare2.RecipientsActivity}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at com.sample.postcare2.RecipientsActivity.onCreate(RecipientsActivity.java:63)
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
01-06 11:53:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: @geet Kindly, find the logcat file above

Comment: what is line 63 in recipientActivity?

Comment: Its at list.setAdapter(m_adapter); in Oncreate method.. I have shown it in the code above too.

Comment: Think setContentView should come after savedInstanceState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing

```
 list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rec_list);
```

before you do

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipients);
```

please, move the setContentView to the first line, otherwise findViewById is not able to find anything, and thats why you get the nullpointer